# Avoid Primitives in API design?

Tags: java, api, primitive

I am designing an API. It will have a lot of methods which do the same, but have a different parameter primitives.

```
public void someMethod1(int x);
public void someMethod1(float x);
public void someMethod1(double x);
public void someMethod2(int x, int y);
...
public void someMethod3(int x, int y, int z);
...
```

Due to the primitives, I have to copy & paste a lot, which I think is quite unmaintainable over time. Is it a good idea to avoid primitives in methods and constructors? For instance, the replacement of the above will be:

```
public <T extends Number> void someMethod1(T x);
public <T extends Number> void someMethod2(T x, T y);
public <T extends Number> void someMethod3(T x, T y, T z);
```

Edit:

*What are the downsides of this?*

Comment: Too many questions! You might want to ask multiple questions, you've not just asked about primitives in API design.

Comment: There's no easy solution for this in Java: either you duplicate or  use code generators (that's how, say, Trove has fast TIntLongHashMap, which are only using primitives [and hence much faster than the default Java HashMap]) or you use objects, and live with the huge performance penalty. Auto-(un)boxing millions of primitives and generating millions of needless objects is a sure way to kill the perfs. Which is why for big collections of primitives the default Java API and stuff based on clean OO simply doesn't cut it. That's when you use things like Trove. It comes down to your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be usable, because of autoboxing / autounboxing in Java 1.5 and later.  You can pass an `int` to something that expects an `Integer`, or vice versa, and the cast will happen automatically.  The same applies to return values.

Keep in mind that in the body of your method, you will know little more about your arguments than that they are some form of `Number`.  This will only be suitable if you don't care to differentiate between integer and floating-point representations.

It will not increase your performance - there will be some small penalty for the cast, but you shouldn't worry about that until you discover you have a bottleneck.  For most applications, the difference will be insignificant.

Whether you use a `List` rather than an array should really be decided by your design, but it is generally advisable to use a `List` unless an array is necessarily needed.  `List`s tend to be more flexible, don't need to be resized, have all of the benefits of the `Collections` API, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about `List<T>` vs. `T[]`, both expose details about implementation.

`List<T>` is more maintainable than `T[]` because you can change the List implementation without changing client code.

If the list shouldn't be modified by the client code, `Iterable<T>` would be better, as you expose nothing about your implementation details and prevent operations other than iteration.

Comment: Iterable is a nice one! Thank you!

Comment: P.S. I edited the question: this is an answer for the question wether `List<T>` was a good replacement for `T[]`.

Answer (score 1):

APIs are about semantics, so I think the answer to the question as stated (Should I avoid primitives in API design) is that it depends on what your API does.

`int addOne(int integer)` is semantically consistent and won't present many problems with maintenance as it reflects the problem domain.

`Employee getEmployee(int empID)` could be classed as inappropriate and will present maintenance issues if your employee IDs change, say, to Strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid pattern, sometimes used for defining properties in a model-view-controller system. Additionally, if you use ints in the range of -128 to 127, they will be auto-cached by Java if you convert using [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) which can speed things up a bit regarding `Integer` creation. You can also increase the cached range using the property [`java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high`](http://www.jroller.com/ethdsy/entry/jsmc_integer_cache_and_escape) which is always at least 127. It might be the case also that auto-boxing will also use this Integer cache, but I'm unsure. If your class is designed for use in a high-performance environment, I'd consider other alternatives instead and use primitives.